# ListView population (using C#)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

i want to populate a WPF listview programatically.
I think im close to the answer but not solved yet, im using a method to populate the list view, the listview looks like this in XAML

```
<ListView Name="listview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="252" Margin="39,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="gridcontrol">
                <GridViewColumn/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

what i've done so far is:

```
private void FillListView( String[] texto ) {

        GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
        gvc.Header = cmbx2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        gridcontrol.Columns.Add(gvc);

        foreach (String s in texto) {

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Content = s;
            listview.Items.Add(item);

        }

        listview.View = gridcontrol;
    }
```

Comment: Wait ... what's your question?  I just ran your code and it seems to bind the items.

Comment: emm yes it does but you know i want something like:

Comment: col1: value1,value2,value3 and col2: value1..value2 of course this goes up and down but im getting every value on every column?

Comment: this works for a DB based application, so you make a query based on two comboboxes selections, and you should have a column with the results for each time you pressed the button

Comment: Gotcha -- I modified my answer.  You just need to set the `DisplayMemberBinding`.  It's a bit weird to test when binding to strings instead of objects, but possible.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution instead of messing around with ListViewItems would be to populate a collection and databind to it. The trick is to flip the items control on the side so your string collection is displayed as a column instead of row.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Results}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Item1}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Item2}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>

</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Results = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string[]>>();

            FillListView("AAA", new string[] { "A1", "A2", "A3" });
            FillListView("BBB", new string[] { "B1", "B2", "B3" });

            DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string[]>> Results { get; private set; }

        private void FillListView(string header, string[] text)
        {
            Results.Add(Tuple.Create(header, text));
        }
    }
}
```